# Google Wave for .Net

Tags: .net, google-wave

Just got my wave sandbox invite today. Does anyone know of a .NET library for google wave? (client and server)
I'm a c# programmer, not very familiar with the language that the Google samples are written in. It's very existing can't wait to write something for it.

Comment: surely a C# programmer won't have much trouble understanding java :P 

(not that I'm a fan of java, C# is java done right if only it had better support on linux )

Comment: eclipse gives me the most problem.

Comment: Been waiting on my invite for a while.  Let me know if you can help a bother out.

Answer (score 9):

I'm porting the Robot API to ASP.NET if that's what you're after.

Eventually the code will be hosted on [this Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/wave-robot-net-client/) - but there's nothing there yet.

I've got as far as having most of the Java interfaces ported and I can deserialize the JSON, but I haven't done the serialization yet. I probably won't be able to make much progress in the next couple of weeks, but after that I should be able to get back to it. If you're interested in what I've got so far I can try to clean it up a little bit and put it up on the project this weekend. It's really been spiking so far, so I have a shameful lack of tests :(

Note that the sandbox doesn't allow robots to run other than on AppEngine at the moment - if you know any Java at all you might want to follow the [Java Robot Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/java-tutorial.html) to get an idea of the kind of thing you'll be able to do. (I'm hoping to be able to test my port internally so that when the public version launches the ability to connect to non-AppEngine robots, with any luck I'll be ready.)

If you're not talking about the Robot API, could you give more details of what you're after? I haven't looked at any of the other APIs available (or coming) but I believe the gadgets are basically JavaScript.

(Btw, I'm jonskeet@wavesandbox.com if you want to get in touch. I don't look at the sandbox very often though.)

Comment: Im talking about a .NET implementation of both the Extensions API (Robot) and also the Wave Federation protocol. Glad to hear that you've already ported most of it. I assume it's pretty straightforward. let me know if you need a tester.

the federation protocol looks more challenging. the existing documentation is incomplete. i guess figuring out how it works is the fun part. let's start an open source project. maybe we can beat google.

Comment: @Sam: I have no interest in "beating" Google, given that I work for Google :) An implementation of the federation protocol would be interesting, but I'm not looking at that at all at the moment. I'll be happy to just get the Robot API working to start with. It's *reasonably* simple, but there's still a fair amount of code to port, even if most of that code is easy. (I've found a couple of bugs along the way, I might add...)

Comment: @Jon: That would be even better:)

Anyway, if anyone is interested let me know. I have a pretty decent understanding of the protocol now. I think I can do it. What's the best way to start an open source project? (Finding people.etc..)

Comment: Start the project (e.g. code.google.com). Get enough of it working to make it interesting to others. Tweet about it :)

Answer (score 2):

I've done a quick implementation using BING Apis and Skeet's API - http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/09/bingybot-google-wave-bot-written-in.html