# Can we host .NET application on Wave Server instead on IIS Web Server

Tags: iis

I am very new to the term Wave Server. I have a requirement that our web application needs to be hosted on a Wave Server. Our application is written in C#.NET so is there any way to host .NET application on a wave server instead of IIS web server.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281509/google-wave-for-net

Comment: Thanks, but I had already gone through that post before posting my question.

Comment: You may want to give me details about what you have done, what isn't working.